# Google Guice. Inject EJB when using Java EE5

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, guice, java-ee-5

It is possible to use Google Guice (any other DI framework) for injecting EJBs in Java EE 5? By default Java EE 5 uses JNDI to injecting EJBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no direct experience with Guice - but yes, it's possible to use other frameworks for injecting EJBs in a JEE5 application. For instance, [Seam](http://www.seamframework.org/) does just that. So in principle, it should be possible as there isn't an inherent restriction in the kind of objects that can be injected, as long as the framework takes care of all the lookup details.

**UPDATE:**

Take a look at this [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20110515231916/http://a-developer-life.blogspot.com/2010/11/injecting-into-ejb3-with-google-guice.html) detailing how to inject EJBs using Guice.

Comment: The post has been taken down fyi

Comment: @VeenarM I swapped the link out with a link to the page on wayback machine

Comment: An alternative blog post detailing how to do it is [here](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/03/guice-tutorial-part-3-integrating-guice.html)

Comment: This answer is partially correct, as EJB can not exist outside of EJB (Java EE) container. In this case it is not EJB anymore, but just POJO.